# setPersistenceEnabled() Error if open app by Notification when app is in background

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

i am writing a chat application.
I have enabled firebase database real-time persistence in the main activity.
With this code:

```kotlin
 if(ref == null) {
            var database =
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(DB_URL)
            database.setPersistenceEnabled(true)
            ref = database.reference

            val chatRef = database!!.getReference("chats")
            chatRef.keepSynced(true)
        }
```

When I send a message to a user, and the user clicks on the notification, the application should open to an application fragment.
If the application is closed it works, if it is in the background it gives me the error:

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.modolo.healthyplus, PID: 16269
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.modolo.healthyplus/com.modolo.healthyplus.MainActivity}: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Calls to setPersistenceEnabled() must be made before any other usage of FirebaseDatabase instance.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3763)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3937)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2288)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8293)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:556)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1045)
     Caused by: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Calls to setPersistenceEnabled() must be made before any other usage of FirebaseDatabase instance.
        at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.assertUnfrozen(FirebaseDatabase.java:332)
        at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.setPersistenceEnabled(FirebaseDatabase.java:285)
        at com.modolo.healthyplus.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:72)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8241)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8207)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1329)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3736)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3937) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2288) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8293) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:556) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1045)
```

this is in log since i close the application and leave it in background:

```
D/DecorView[]: onWindowFocusChanged hasWindowFocus false
D/WebSocket: ws_0 - ws message: {"t":"d","d":{"b":{"p":"chats/kedgdOemYBP5XP0OuuMLYjpkyEe2f8OGIg86xxTM9v6OANszhwYnyRk1/messages/-NMUWfPTd-CqO3VPdinu","d":{"createdAt":"2023-01-23T16:47:05.005Z","message":"test","senderId":"f8OGIg86xxTM9v6OANszhwYnyRk1","type":"text"}},"a":"d"}}
D/WebSocket: ws_0 - Reset keepAlive. Remaining: 33012
D/WebSocket: ws_0 - HandleNewFrameCount: 1
D/WebSocket: ws_0 - handleIncomingFrame complete frame: {t=d, d={a=d, b={p=chats/kedgdOemYBP5XP0OuuMLYjpkyEe2f8OGIg86xxTM9v6OANszhwYnyRk1/messages/-NMUWfPTd-CqO3VPdinu, d={createdAt=2023-01-23T16:47:05.005Z, senderId=f8OGIg86xxTM9v6OANszhwYnyRk1, message=test, type=text}}}}
D/Connection: conn_0 - received data message: {a=d, b={p=chats/kedgdOemYBP5XP0OuuMLYjpkyEe2f8OGIg86xxTM9v6OANszhwYnyRk1/messages/-NMUWfPTd-CqO3VPdinu, d={createdAt=2023-01-23T16:47:05.005Z, senderId=f8OGIg86xxTM9v6OANszhwYnyRk1, message=test, type=text}}}
D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - handleServerMessage: d {p=chats/kedgdOemYBP5XP0OuuMLYjpkyEe2f8OGIg86xxTM9v6OANszhwYnyRk1/messages/-NMUWfPTd-CqO3VPdinu, d={createdAt=2023-01-23T16:47:05.005Z, senderId=f8OGIg86xxTM9v6OANszhwYnyRk1, message=test, type=text}}
D/WebSocket: ws_0 - ws message: {"t":"d","d":{"b":{"p":"chats/f8OGIg86xxTM9v6OANszhwYnyRk1kedgdOemYBP5XP0OuuMLYjpkyEe2/messages/-NMUWfQQ4fTWEa_tiPkn","d":{"createdAt":"2023-01-23T16:47:05.005Z","message":"test","senderId":"f8OGIg86xxTM9v6OANszhwYnyRk1","type":"text"}},"a":"d"}}
D/RepoOperation: onDataUpdate: /chats/kedgdOemYBP5XP0OuuMLYjpkyEe2f8OGIg86xxTM9v6OANszhwYnyRk1/messages/-NMUWfPTd-CqO3VPdinu
D/RepoOperation: onDataUpdate: /chats/kedgdOemYBP5XP0OuuMLYjpkyEe2f8OGIg86xxTM9v6OANszhwYnyRk1/messages/-NMUWfPTd-CqO3VPdinu {createdAt=2023-01-23T16:47:05.005Z, senderId=f8OGIg86xxTM9v6OANszhwYnyRk1, message=test, type=text}
D/Persistence: Starting transaction.
D/Persistence: Persisted a total of 1 rows and deleted 0 rows for a set at /chats/kedgdOemYBP5XP0OuuMLYjpkyEe2f8OGIg86xxTM9v6OANszhwYnyRk1/messages/-NMUWfPTd-CqO3VPdinu in 3ms
D/Persistence: Transaction completed. Elapsed: 9ms
D/WebSocket: ws_0 - Reset keepAlive. Remaining: 44978
D/WebSocket: ws_0 - HandleNewFrameCount: 1
D/WebSocket: ws_0 - handleIncomingFrame complete frame: {t=d, d={a=d, b={p=chats/f8OGIg86xxTM9v6OANszhwYnyRk1kedgdOemYBP5XP0OuuMLYjpkyEe2/messages/-NMUWfQQ4fTWEa_tiPkn, d={createdAt=2023-01-23T16:47:05.005Z, senderId=f8OGIg86xxTM9v6OANszhwYnyRk1, message=test, type=text}}}}
D/Connection: conn_0 - received data message: {a=d, b={p=chats/f8OGIg86xxTM9v6OANszhwYnyRk1kedgdOemYBP5XP0OuuMLYjpkyEe2/messages/-NMUWfQQ4fTWEa_tiPkn, d={createdAt=2023-01-23T16:47:05.005Z, senderId=f8OGIg86xxTM9v6OANszhwYnyRk1, message=test, type=text}}}
D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - handleServerMessage: d {p=chats/f8OGIg86xxTM9v6OANszhwYnyRk1kedgdOemYBP5XP0OuuMLYjpkyEe2/messages/-NMUWfQQ4fTWEa_tiPkn, d={createdAt=2023-01-23T16:47:05.005Z, senderId=f8OGIg86xxTM9v6OANszhwYnyRk1, message=test, type=text}}
D/RepoOperation: onDataUpdate: /chats/f8OGIg86xxTM9v6OANszhwYnyRk1kedgdOemYBP5XP0OuuMLYjpkyEe2/messages/-NMUWfQQ4fTWEa_tiPkn
D/RepoOperation: onDataUpdate: /chats/f8OGIg86xxTM9v6OANszhwYnyRk1kedgdOemYBP5XP0OuuMLYjpkyEe2/messages/-NMUWfQQ4fTWEa_tiPkn {createdAt=2023-01-23T16:47:05.005Z, senderId=f8OGIg86xxTM9v6OANszhwYnyRk1, message=test, type=text}
D/Persistence: Starting transaction.
D/Persistence: Persisted a total of 1 rows and deleted 0 rows for a set at /chats/f8OGIg86xxTM9v6OANszhwYnyRk1kedgdOemYBP5XP0OuuMLYjpkyEe2/messages/-NMUWfQQ4fTWEa_tiPkn in 2ms
D/Persistence: Transaction completed. Elapsed: 4ms
W/olo.healthyplu: Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->add(I)Z (unsupported,test-api, reflection, allowed)
W/olo.healthyplu: Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->add(ILjava/lang/String;)Z (unsupported,test-api, reflection, allowed)
W/olo.healthyplu: Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->get(I)I (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
W/olo.healthyplu: Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->getName(I)Ljava/lang/String; (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
W/System: A resource failed to call close. 
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 160794467; UID 10624; state: DISABLED
D/AppScoutStateMachine: 26520-ScoutStateMachinecreated
```

I don't understand why the error gives me only in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite explicit:

> alls to setPersistenceEnabled() must be made before any other usage of FirebaseDatabase instance.

So apparently there are some cases where you call `setPersistenceEnabled()` after you've already **used** the database (read from it, or wrote to it), which isn't allowed.

It's impossible for us to say why that is from the code you shared, but if you log your database calls it should be fairly quick to spot the flow.

Comment: i added the database log, but i don't understand, if i set persistence in main activity, how is it possible to do some actions before that?